# How to make an image scroll forever

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am trying to make an image scroll to the end of the screen automatically and then jump back to the beginning of the image and scroll again in a continuous loop. I don't want the user to know that the end of the image was released? Does anyone know how to make that? The image must scroll by itself, not because the user touched it, that's why I can't use the WWDC Video. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Judging by your comments, you are as you say a Noob. So why not go out, pick yourself up a book from the store and learn like that rather than expecting source code from people? StackOverflow is for help, not for doing your work.

Comment: I am a noob, but I never came on here expecting code. I don't even know what this kind of thing is called, how would I find a book that explains it? I am not new stack overflow. I know how it works. But to point me out on a question that I legitimately don't have any idea about is really a mean move. If this was our attitude then why don't you tells very one to just go find books about what they are trying to do, then we wouldn't even have a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could scroll two UIImageViews by adding to/subtracting from their x values. when one scrolls off the screen, you could then set its x value to be immediately behind the second one, and continue scrolling.

EX: ([ ] is the screen)

```
<------------------------------------

|   [ A ]   |     B    |
|     A[   ]|     B    |
|     A   [ | ]   B    |
            [   ] B    |     A     |
```

Comment: Look for the -didScroll callback from UIScrollView to do your view layout.

Comment: Could you give me a link for a tutorial or write some sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A UIScrollView with an UIImage subview within it. Add a timer to the mix and you are done.
This should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Could you show me a bit of code or a tutorial where they do this? Sorry i'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: Not sure this is what he means. Not going to down vote, but what does a timer have to do with scrolling an image?

Comment: The timer will scroll the scroll view rather than the user

Comment: Exactly, thanks Jonathan. The scrollview gets scrolled by the time, and there are two UIImage subview's inside of it, side by side of the same image. This is to allow seamless scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do parallax scrolling.  I don't think UIKit supports this, but the Cocos2d game engine does.  That might be the easiest path.

Comment: Using Cococ2d or any other framework when the base understanding of the technology at hand is weak is a bad move, imo. It is like learning jQuery before vanilla Javascript and then never knowing why and how it works.